# Kill jquery ajax form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am remotely submitting a form potentially several times in close succession. For this particular case, debouncing is not an option. I am looking for the jQuery equivalent of `.abort()` for remote forms submitted using `.submit()` so I can cancel all previous submissions when a new one is made.

Thanks in advance,
Garrett

Answer (score 2):

What I did is attach to the beforeSend event of the form, store the xhr object as part of the form's data, and abort it if a new request is enqueued:

```
$('form').bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(evt, xhr) {
  console.log('Enqueued new xhr request');
  var prevXhr = $(this).data('current-xhr');
  if (prevXhr) {
    prevXhr.abort();
    console.log('Aborting previous xhr request');
  }
  $(this).data('current-xhr', xhr);
});
```

And you can still use the `:remote => true` option in the form straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use jQuery [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to queue your submits and [.clearQueue()](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) to clear the queue when needed. Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem. If the form is submitted, a request is sent to the server... so, how can you abort that?

If by abort you mean, cancelling the processing of the response, just use a control variable that you increase/decrease to know if there are pending requests.

From the API: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ you can't do that.

Comment: Yes, I would like to cancel processing of the response. The problem is that the server doesn't necessarily send back the responses in the order the requests are received, so a simple request counter won't let me determine which response is the most recent (unless I'm being daft and not seeing something). I could include the counter in the request and return it in the response, but I would like to avoid server-side involvement if possible.